# Hey, my function dont delete anything why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have rock,paper,scissors program with score. Evryrthing works fine, but my delete function is not deliting anything.Why? Here is the function:

```
def delete_line_by_full_match(original_file, line_to_delete):
    """ In a file, delete the lines at line number in given list"""
    is_skipped = False
    dummy_file = original_file + '.bak'
    # Open original file in read only mode and dummy file in write mode
    with open(original_file, 'r') as read_obj, open(dummy_file, 'w') as write_obj:
        # Line by line copy data from original file to dummy file
        for line in read_obj:
            line_to_match = line
            if line[-1] == '\n':
                line_to_match = line[:-1]
            # if current line matches with the given line then skip that line
            if line_to_match != line_to_delete:
                write_obj.write(line)
            else:
                is_skipped = True

    # If any line is skipped then rename dummy file as original file
```

And here is the program:

```
import random
import os

def get_score_for_name(path_to_file, name,score_out):
    with open(path_to_file) as file_handler:
        for name_ in file_handler:
            name_list = name_.split()
            if name_list[0] == name:
                score_out.append(name_list[1])
    return score_out

def check(filev,path_to_file, name,score_out,filew,namezr):
    if name in filev:
        get_score_for_name(path_to_file, name,score_out)
    else:
        filew.write(namezr)
        score_out.append("0")

def delete_line_by_full_match(original_file, line_to_delete):
    """ In a file, delete the lines at line number in given list"""
    is_skipped = False
    dummy_file = original_file + '.bak'
    # Open original file in read only mode and dummy file in write mode
    with open(original_file, 'r') as read_obj, open(dummy_file, 'w') as write_obj:
        # Line by line copy data from original file to dummy file
        for line in read_obj:
            line_to_match = line
            if line[-1] == '\n':
                line_to_match = line[:-1]
            # if current line matches with the given line then skip that line
            if line_to_match != line_to_delete:
                write_obj.write(line)
            else:
                is_skipped = True

    # If any line is skipped then rename dummy file as original file
    if is_skipped:
        os.remove(original_file)
        os.rename(dummy_file, original_file)
    else:
        os.remove(dummy_file)

def game(scoredef,filename,scorestrer,name):
    while 5:        
        clist = ("scissors","paper","rock")
        a = input()
        b = random.choice(clist)
        if a == b:
            print("There is a draw","(" + b + ")")
            scoredef += 50
        elif a == "scissors":
            if b == "paper":
                print("Well done. Computer chose", b, "and failed")
                scoredef += 100
            elif b == "rock":
                print("Sorry, but computer chose", b)
        elif a == "paper":
            if b == "scissors":
                print("Sorry, but computer chose", b)
            elif b == "rock":
                print("Well done. Computer chose", b, "and failed")
                scoredef += 100
        elif a == "rock":
            if b == "scissors":
                print("Well done. Computer chose", b, "and failed")
                scoredef += 100
            elif b == "paper":
                print("Sorry, but computer chose", b)
        elif a == "!rating":
            print(scoredef)
        elif a == "!exit":
            print("Bye!")
            someintstr = 0
            scorestrnow = str(scoredef)
            namenow = name + " " + scorestrnow + "\n"
            namebefore = name + " " + scorestr
            delete_line_by_full_match(filename,namebefore)
            with open(filename,"a") as f:
                f.write(namenow)
                f.close()
            break


name = input("Enter your name: ")
namez = name + " "+ "0" + "\n"
fr = open("rating.txt",'r')
fa = open("rating.txt",'a')
fileread = fr.read()
lister =[]
print("Hello,",name)
check(fileread,"rating.txt",name,lister,fa,namez)
scorestr = "".join(lister)
score = int(scorestr)
game(score,"rating.txt",scorestr,name)
```

Comment: Well done for posting what looks like a complete piece of code - the `delete_line_by_full_match` function looks like you should be able to simply test it on a file (i.e. not with any game logic around it - have you tried that? Have you tried simple debugging tactics like printing the lines that are being compared and the result of comparing them so understand the flow of your code as it scans the file?

Comment: Man, I tried like 4 functions from stack overflow,tried to do it my self, but it simple dont work, I tried debuging but dont help cuz that is function that simply delete one line from whole file, I know that problem is with all oder code,but I dont know where it is and how to solve it

Comment: the problem is that you are not closing the filehandles `fr` and `fa`. Use `with` or explicitly `.close()` these handles, otherwise `rating.txt` cannot be modified during `delete_line_by_full_match`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, the fix is to close the open file handles:

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
namez = name + " "+ "0" + "\n"
fr = open("rating.txt",'r')
fa = open("rating.txt",'a')
fileread = fr.read()
fr.close()  # <- close the handle!
lister =[]
print("Hello,",name)
check(fileread,"rating.txt",name,lister,fa,namez)
fa.close()  # <- close the handle!
scorestr = "".join(lister)
score = int(scorestr)
game(score,"rating.txt",scorestr,name)
```

or, even better, use `with open("rating.txt")` in each case